# <h:selectOneMenu> and lazy loading from hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, lazy-loading

In my JSF application I have quite simple piece of code. I want user to choose one value from collection in `<h:selectOneMenu>`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{dao.valuesFromDb}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`#{bean.value}` is of type `Region`, and `#{dao.valuesFromDb}` returns list of `Regions`. The problem is, `Region` in bean is lazy loaded from hibernate, which wraps it in some wrapper, class looks like `my.package.Region_$$_javassist_15@25183`.

If `#{bean.value}` has some value set, it should be preselected on the page if it is in list of values (`#{dao.valuesFromDb}`). Problem is it is checked by `equals` method, which returns `false` because types are different.

How to solve this problem? Is it possible to force JSF not to use `equals`, but somehow handle this comparison myself? Overriding `equals` so it ignores type is IMHO really bad idea, as it can break `equals` symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I would avoid the problem altogether by eagerly fetching the `Region` in `bean`.

Mucking about with equals() will result in far less clear code than simply fetching the information JSF wants to make the comparison. And as you point out, it's likely to have unintended consequences.

Comment: I simply can't. We have many dependent entities and we just exceeded limit of joins in single query. We had to change some eager loading to lazy.

Comment: Interesting problem. 

When I've had similar problems (deep graph), I've separately hydrated the associated object(s) and just set it on the target bean. I've had to do it to avoid Cartesian joins due to multiple collections.

Comment: we had also some problem with cartesian joins. Can you share some link explaining it?

Comment: You can start with the Hibernate documentation. Section 14.3 includes the statements "It is possible to create a cartesian product by join fetching more than one collection in a query, so take care in this case. Join fetching multiple collection roles can produce unexpected results for bag mappings, so user discretion is advised when formulating queries in this case." This corresponds to my experience, and frequently requires a lot of trial and error to find the right solution. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

We decided to resolve this issue in our Override ’equals’ methods. The important trick is never to reference the foreign object's attributes directly within the equals method, but always use getters. Then Hibernate seems to dig out the correct values from the within the javassist object.

In your case the Region equals method should look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {return true;}
    if (obj == null) {return false;}
    if (!(obj instanceof Region)) {return false;}

    Region region = (Region) obj;

    if ((name == null) && (region.getName() != null)) {return false;}  // Do NOT use 'region.name' here
    else if (!name.equals(region.getName())) {return false;}           // Do NOT use 'region.name' here
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the fetch type to EAGER, you can pre-load the bean by invoking the `Region` getter in the action (of the controller) that forwards to your view. I.e: just call the `bean.getRegion()` method.

This way you won't get the LazyInitializationException (if that's what you're getting).